# re-initialize class onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lmug6L0n/25/).

I have a class `numberonly` it works on load page, but when I append input it is not working on text box.

I know it not re-initialize after I append `input` that is my main aim to append event on append.

This is my html:: (Please see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lmug6L0n/25/))

```
<div id='addinputdiv'>
  <input type="text" class='numberonly' />
 </div>
<button onclick="addinputt()">Add Input</button>
```

`numberonly` class have on key down and key up events, I want to bind it on new input append.

Comment: your fiddle is not working

Comment: @Max updated https://jsfiddle.net/Lmug6L0n/25/

Comment: so you want to that input only can type number?

Comment: if so change type to number from text

Comment: Yes, new input type have number only as defined for its class

Comment: `numberonly` class have on key down and key up events, I want to bind it on new input

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168030/discussion-between-max-and-ankit-soni).